# Generalized limit in $\mathcal{L} _{\infty}$ (Using: Hahn Banach Extension Theorem)

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, hahn-banach-theorem

I am trying to proof the same as the question bellow, but for bounded functions over a field $\mathbb{K}$. p is defined the same way as the question but we are taking the limit of a function when it's variable goes to $\infty$
[image]

[Generalized limit in $l_\infty$ (Using: Hahn Banach Extension Theorem)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2423921/generalized-limit-in-l-infty-using-hahn-banach-extension-theorem?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I have no problem with the further proof, after definition of $p$, but I'm not getting how to prove the following:

1. p is well defined in $\mathcal{L} _{\infty}$
2. p is subadditive
3. if $a \leq \phi(x) \leq b,  \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ then $a \leq p(\phi) \leq b $
4. $p(\phi(s) - \phi(s+a)) = 0, \forall \phi \in \mathcal{L}_{\infty}$

Comment: If you can't even prove (1) then you are in serious trouble.  Recall $x\in\ell_\infty$ means there is an $M\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\lvert x_m\rvert<M$ for every $m$.  Now use triangle inequality then take limsup and inf...

Comment: @user10354138 I shouldn't have put (1), thanks for the answer. It is quite easy using the fact that $\phi \in \mathbb{L}_{\infty}$. I made (2) until a certain extend, where I would have the wrong side of the inequality with the inf. And I'm having a lot of trouble with (4), even though it seems intuitive.